# DAC quality effect on Bluetooth music streaming

Tags: pi-4, audio, bluetooth

I want to transmit music(Spotify and mp3 files) to my Bluetooth speakers from my Raspberry Pi. I have read that the onboard DAC on Pi isn't good so use an external DAC with better sound quality.

However in this case, I believe using the Pi's builtin DAC or the external DAC won't have any effect on the audio quality. The analog to digital conversion will only happen when BT stream is received by the speaker. Thus the audio quality will solely depend upon DAC capabilities on the Bluetooth speaker. Correct?

The BT speakers do support aptX HD and aptX LL, but my current USB BT 5.1 dongle doesn't support it. Will switching to a aptX compatible USB transceiver make a noticeable difference in sound quality?

Lastly, do I need to change something in the software to make use of these codecs and changing to a different codec or it's something done automatically at the hardware level by the transceiver?

Comment: Seems like the following blog has the information you are looking for: https://medium.com/@multi.flexi/use-aptx-on-linux-3f3c4d597dcd

Comment: @ukBaz Thanks for the link. It points me in the right direction